# Cual es la diferencia al usar el operador?

Tags: css3

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar el selector `>` y no usarlo? , ya que ***observo el mismo resultado.***

```css
ul > li {
 color: red;
}

ol li {
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Hola</li>
</ul>

<ol>
<li>Chau!</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: "ul > li" selecciona a los li que son hijos directos de ul, mientras que "ol li" selecciona a los li contenidos en ol, sean o no hijos directos. En este caso es lo mismo porque tu <li>es hija directa de un <ul>. Aqui esta bien explicado: [CSS - Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le asigna estilo a cada **li** donde el elemento padre es **ul**

```css
ul > li {
 color: red;
}

ol li {
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<span><li>Chau!</li></span>
</ul>

<ol>
<span><li>Chau!</li></span>
</ol>
```

Comment: Gracias Oren Diaz !

Comment: No hay por que Eduardo